# How to detect phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I  have a enterprise network. I tried to use nessus and other scanners but I couldnt. I want to detect all servers which have phpmailer. How can I do this ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking in the wrong way. PHPMailer is not visible by scanning from outside;  it does not run a network service. It's a programming library used by web applications, so you need to search the source code of your apps to find uses of it. Searching for the filename `class.phpmailer.php` would be appropriate.

When you find it, make sure it's been updated to [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0):

If `find` is installed than next `find / -name class.phpmailer.php` will return location of `class.phpmailer.php`. 
If `find / -name class.phpmailer.php` doesn't return anything then PHPMailer wasn't installed.